# Customize the validation error messages of validation.js in magento

Tags: validation, magento, magento-1.7

In my magento application the checkout page , will displays error message using validation.js file.

when i click to continue in the new billing address without entereing some value it displays error message as `This is required field`..

I want to change this message as its corresponding field name .

[image]

Instead of that error message i need to display as `First name is a required field`..

How can i do this ?

**EDIT**

this is the input box which is located in customer/widget/name.phtml as:

```
<input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('firstname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text validate-firstname" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
```

[image]

This is the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create another class in your validation.js file something like `validate-firstname` 
and add something like this in your validation.js file

```
 ['validate-firstname', 'First name is required field.', function(v) {
            return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
        }],
```

Search for this `validate-alpha` validation line and after put this code in your js file and add `validate-firstname` class in your firstname input field.

Comment: ,if i need some more validation for last  name, email, address, stae etc... what will i do?. same will be repeated for each one?

Comment: Yes email validation and address validation class is already there in validation.js file

Comment: it will displays an alert box with two error message when i give the validation like your answer

Answer (score 0):

Add new rule to Validation like below and use that class for input.created new rule **required-entry-productids** and add class **required-entry-productids** to input.

```
 Validation.add('required-entry-productids', "Select the atlest one item you would like to return.", function(v) {
            return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
        });
```