# Custom validation message for my checkbox

Tags: magento

I have below terms and condition checkbox created for a form

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" class="checkbox required-entry" value="value">
```

I am getting "this is required field" as validation message but I want to change it to "Please check our terms and condition". Please suggest.

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557820/customize-the-validation-error-messages-of-validation-js-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

```
['validate-firstname', 'First name is required field.', function(v) {
            return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
        }],
```

modify or add one rule in validation js like above code.